Reading a text file with a hh:mm:ss mixed with floats
I have a txt file like this :
index   timestamp   polarisation current (A)    signal (V)  head temperature (°C)   head relat.humidity (%RH)   MUGS temperature (°C)   laser voltage (V)   laser current (A)   driver temperature (°C)
0   16:11:24    0.4 0.0006019   26.51   43.5    32.0    11.37   0.3922  26.5
1   16:11:29    0.402   0.0006286   26.51   43.5    32.5    11.41   0.3972  31.5
2   16:11:34    0.404   0.0005828   26.51   43.5    32.5    11.42   0.4048  32.5
3   16:11:38    0.406   0.0006139   26.51   43.5    32.5    11.39   0.3984  32.5

The full file is here ( https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2izelcpjpqr8yckowtgat/35deg_400mA_640mA_120pts_-0.015mA_mod1_LAS5000Hz_LI10000Hz_meth2_0.15us_-14h02m33s_pulse20.txt?rlkey=3xwxthp6v48deyeob0gj6uuo7&st=xta4m25q&dl=0 )
I read that file with :
with open(universal_path,'rt'): 
        values = np.genfromtxt( universal_path, delimiter="", skip_header = 1, encoding='unicode_escape')

But the problem is that the second column is full of NaN :  
I tried to write dtype = None. But now it read only the first column of the txt file :

I tried to write dtype = [int, str, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float]. But it only reads the firts column too.
How can i do to read the second column as a string pls ?

"I have a txt file" -- so why do you give us its screenshot? That makes it rather difficult to try to reproduce your problem (if you think anyone will bother re-typing it, think again).

"But it now also read the first column." -- what does that exactly mean? I mean it read the first column before as well, why is that suddenly a problem?

@DanMašek I thought sharing files on stackoverflow was forbidden. My bad. I added the full file

@DanMašek I clarified what "but it now also read the first column" meant.

To get the second column as string, pass converters={1 : str} to genfromtxt (no need specifying dtype). Works here, although with an older version on Numpy.

Of course, instead of str you could give it a lambda that uses datetime.strptime (or related) to parse the time.

I suppose this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658522/loading-a-date-in-numpy-genfromtxt

BTW, the with open(...) is kinda useless in your example, you open the file, but don't really do anything with it (and since you call np.genfromtxt with the path, it opens it the second time).

@DanMašek Thank you for the with open(...) delete tips. I deleted it and it works like before.
But adding  converters={1 : str} doesn't work for me. It only reads the first column of the file. And says the array associated is of type void928

I don't know then. Tested it now with your complete file, with Numpy 1.21.6 as well as 2.1.2. A simple np.genfromtxt('test.data', skip_header=1, encoding='unicode_escape', converters={0:int, 1 : str}) parses all the 120 lines. This is the first one: (  0, '13:52:46', 0.4  , 0.0006121, 25.21, 44.93, 29.5, 3.27, 0.3913, 26.5).

you could consider pandas to read the file.
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(universal_path, **kwargs)

@DanMašek Okay. Its weird. When i type np.genfromtxt('test.data', skip_header=1, encoding='unicode_escape', converters={0:int, 1 : str}) it returns me the right thing.
But when i type test = np.genfromtxt('test.data', skip_header=1, encoding='unicode_escape', converters={0:int, 1 : str}) it says that the test matrix is a 120 line matric of type void832. There is only the first column of the data file in that matric. What can i do ?

Oh yes, I've noticed there's a difference in presentation, your code looked like a list of lists, but after the change it was a list of tuples. And now that you mention it, the shape was 1-D. Might be due to having that string in there, the 10-tuple is the only value it parses. And then whatever it is you're using to visualize the result only prints the first element of that tuple. I wonder how/if we can make it return the proper number of columns (for a numpy array, having strings in is a bit weird).

I mean you can do a quick and dirty list(map(list, test)) to turn it into a list of lists. However just simply turning that back into a np.array gives me an array of strings... TBH I haven't really used such heterogenous arrays in numpy, so I don't know what to suggest right now. Do some reading and maybe consider using Pandas like someone suggested -- IIRC that is better suited to such things.

@DanMašek Oh yeah thanks. Using what you said i got what i wanted :
`def lecture_(universal_path):
val_array = np.array(np.genfromtxt(universal_path, delimiter="", skip_header=1, encoding='unicode_escape', converters={0:int, 1 : str}).tolist())
hh_min_ss = np.array([i.split(':', 2) for i in val_array[:,1]]).astype(float)
s = hh_min_ss[:,0]*3600 + hh_min_ss[:,1]*60 + hh_min_ss[:,2]

val_array[:,1] = s
return val_array.astype(float)`


Great. Feel free to write an answer based on that, I'm on the road now and will be for the rest of the week so won't have time to do so.

With what @Dan Masek said, i have this code that works :
import numpy as np

from pathlib import Path

def lecture_EMUGS(universal_path):
    val_array = np.array(np.genfromtxt(universal_path, delimiter="", 
    skip_header=1, encoding='unicode_escape', converters={0:int, 1 : 
    str}).tolist())

    hh_min_ss = np.array([i.split(':', 2) for i in 
    val_array[:,1]]).astype(float)
    s = hh_min_ss[:,0]*3600 + hh_min_ss[:,1]*60 + hh_min_ss[:,2]

    val_array[:,1] = s
return val_array.astype(float)

universal_path =
Path(r"35deg_400mA_640mA_120pts_~0.015mA_mod1_LAS5000Hz_LI10000Hz_meth2
_0.15us_-14h02m33s_pulse20% (1).txt")
data = lecture_EMUGS(universal_path)



    

.tolist() converts what np.genfromtxt produced into a list. np.array() converts this list into a numy array.
hh_min_ss converts a one column string array into a 3 column float array. s converts the "hh:mm:ss" string into the number of second it represents.
Then val_array[:,1] = s replace the string column by the float column it represents in seconds.

could you please correct your indentation so everyone can test or use tour solution as is?

@folengateis What do you want me to correct ? I don't understand

here's a rudimentary conversion using duckdb (i've mangled the column names into something 'reasonable' imo), the resultant dictionary can be manipulated using numpy functions
import duckdb as ddb

conn =ddb.connect() #in memory db, disappears when closed

conn.execute("""create table camile as SELECT *
    FROM read_csv('test.csv',
    delim = '\t',
    header = true,
    columns = {
    'index': 'integer',
    'timestamp': 'time',
    'polarisation-current': 'double',
    'signal': 'double',
    'head-temp': 'double',
    'head-relat-humidity': 'double',
    'MUGS-temp': 'double',
    'laser-voltage': 'double',
    'laser-current': 'double',
    'driver-temp': 'double'
    } ); """
)

myData = conn.sql("SELECT * from camile").fetchnumpy()

conn.close()

# print first 5 items ... 
for key, values in myData.items():
    print(f"{key}: {values[:5]}")

#
#  read https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/export_numpy.html
#


It probably works. I'll try it on my personnal computer this evening. Thanks for your answer. I added a solution on the commentary above.
